# Pattern with bitwise operators

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

How do I set the bits of a variable to assume the pattern I want? 
For exemple, if I have to print this sequence, how do i proceed?

```
11010010 11010010 11010010 11010010
```

I wrote the code that print and separate bits in this configuration, but don't know how to set them as I want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
int a;
void stampabit(a);
int main()
{
    int i;
    int n= sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT;
    int mask = 1 << (n-1);

    for (i=1; i<=n; ++i){
        putchar(((a & mask)==0)?'0':'1');
        a<<=1;
        if(i%CHAR_BIT==0 && i<n)
            putchar(' ');
    }
}
```

Comment: `a` and `mask` should be `unsigned` because you are shifting into the m.s. bit (otherwise the sign bit). In this case `unsigned a = 0xd2d2d2d2;`

Comment: Your unimplemented function `void stampabit(a);` would need to be `unsigned stampabit(void);` or `void stampabit(unsigned *a);` but it is unclear what you are trying to do. Perhaps you intend to call `stampabit` 32 times to shove bits into `a`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must shift mask instead of shift the variable

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
unsigned int a = 0xAA55AA55;

int main()
{
    size_t i;
    unsigned int  n= sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT;
    unsigned int  mask = 1 << (n-1);

    for (i=1; i<=n; ++i){
        putchar(((a & mask)==0)?'0':'1');
        mask>>=1;
        if(i%CHAR_BIT==0 && i<n)
            putchar(' ');
    }
    putchar('\n');
}
```

Output will be

```
10101010 01010101 10101010 01010101
```

Changing value of `a` to `0xD2D2D2D2` as you want output will be

```
11010010 11010010 11010010 11010010
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Why you used 0xAA55AA55 ?

Comment: To have a value to display because global variable are 0 inited. The value itself is a professional deformation ;)

Comment: That's really useful. How can I found the value for the bits I need?

Comment: You're welcome.  Remember to close the question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
if you need just set some bits, simply use bitwise or,
and if you need to clear some bits, use bitwise and:

```
uint32_t   a=1;
a |= 0xD2D2D2D2 ; //set bits to 11010010 11010010 11010010 11010010
a &= ~1; // clear first bit (or mask)
```

and it is good to separate display code from main code to have clear code:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdint.h>

void print_bits(uint32_t u){
    int i=31;
    do{
        if (u & 0x80000000) putchar('1'); else putchar('0');
        u <<= 1;
        if(i%8 == 0) putchar(' ');
    }while( --i >= 0);  
} 

int main(){  
    uint32_t   a=1;
    a |= 0xD2D2D2D2 ; //set bits to 11010010 11010010 11010010 11010010
    a &= ~1; // clear first bit (or mask) 
    print_bits(a); //output: 11010010 11010010 11010010 11010010
}
```

Old:
if you need just set some bits, simply use bitwise or like this:

```
void stampabit(int setBits){
    a |= setBits;
}
```

to set your pattern 11010010 11010010 11010010 11010010 use this:

```
stampabit(0xD2D2D2D2 ); // stampabit(0b11010010110100101101001011010010);
```

working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
//#include <stdint.h>
int a=0;
void stampabit(int setBits){
    a |= setBits;
}
int main()
{
    int i;
    stampabit(0xD2D2D2D2 ); // stampabit(0b11010010110100101101001011010010);
    int n= sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT; // number of bits in int (8, 16, 32, 64, ... bits)
    int mask = 1 << (n-1); // sign bit mask

    for (i=1; i<=n; ++i){
        putchar(((a & mask)==0)?'0':'1');
        a<<=1;
        if(i%CHAR_BIT==0 && i<n)
            putchar(' ');
    }
}
```

output:

```
11010010 11010010 11010010 11010010
```

Some notes:
here it is just sample code and it works fine, but using unsigned types is clearly shows you don't need sign bit, and it is bug proof.
using local variables or shifting local variables is better than using or shifting global variables, unless it is intentional.

last but not least if you don't need platform dependent int use  int32_t or uint32_t from

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

and if you need to clear some bits, use bitwise and:

```
uint32_t   a=1;
a |= 0xD2D2D2D2 ; //set bits to 11010010 11010010 11010010 11010010
a &= ~1; // clear first bit (or mask)
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: C doesn't have binary literals `0b...`.

Comment: i am using Dev-Cpp, it supports. but in your case use hex value.

Comment: Dev-cpp is an IDE, not a compiler. Your compiler (probably GCC) supports it as an extension but it isn't standard C.

Comment: `int setBits` ... `0xD2D2D2D2` will not work in well-defined ways if `int` is 32 bits. You are writing data to the sign bit, which doesn't make sense. Similarly `1 << (n-1);` may invoke undefined behavior. You should always use `uint32_t` etc and never `int`. You say "if you don't need platform dependent int...". Why would you ever need that? It's like saying "if you don't need bugs...".

Comment: yes it is compiler (config) dependent, I will provide new sample with uint32_t.